# Not Saving image correctly - $_FILES OR $_GET

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image in a PHTML file. When I try to save an image to the new folder location it saves but as an empty image file. I've tried to use `$_FILES['pic']['name']` but it doesn't return any image. I think it doesn't read anything as it always return a blank value, so I've been using `$_GET['pic']`. It was working yesterday but for some reason it isn't now. Could someone please look at my code because i don't know where i'm going wrong?

Code to save the image file:

```
if (isset($_GET["formCheck"])){
    if (isset($_GET["pic"]) ) {
        $link= $_GET["pic"];
        echo "name: " . $link . "<br>";
        $extension = end(explode('.', $_GET["pic"]));
        $hashedimg = md5($link.time()) . "." . $extension;

        echo $hashedimg . "<br>";
        $destdir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'library' . DS;
        echo "dir: " .$destdir . "<br>";
        $img=file_get_contents($hashedimg);
        file_put_contents($destdir.substr($hashedimg, strrpos($hashedimg,'/')), $img);

        echo "end: " . $extension . "<br>";
        echo "fileloc: " . $destdir . $hashedimg . "<br>";
        $fileloc = $destdir . $hashedimg;

        $_GET["pic"] = $fileloc;
        echo $_GET["pic"];              
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you form has the method POST and it has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: hi, thank you the problem was because i was using get and not post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments:

Make sure you form has the method `post` and it has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0):

You must using form have attribute `enctype=multipart/form-data`, you can upload image/file.

Answer (score 0):

Your form look like below:

```
<form action="<?php echo $url?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `method=GET` to `post` and then `$_FILES['pic']['name']` worked